# Grouping multiple objects with specific position three js

Tags: javascript, angular, three.js, dom-events

I'm working on three js with angular web application and having some issues while setting up exact positions of objects.
as per requirement I've to load all different different objects and will need to setup them in a specific position.

To load different different objects to specific position we'll need to provide x,y,z positions for all different types of objects.

Below is my sample code:

```
this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
        this.scene.add(new THREE.AxisHelper(200));

        var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
        var group = new THREE.Group();

          loader.load('assets/model/Research_development.obj', function (object) {

            var modelScene = object;
            modelScene.position.set(-17,-16,5);
            modelScene.scale.set(5,5,5);
            group.add(modelScene);

          }, undefined, function (error) {
            console.error(error);
          });

            loader.load('assets/model/Sheet_metal.obj', function (object) {

            var modelScene = object;
            modelScene.position.set(-10,-9,5);
            modelScene.scale.set(2,2,2);
            group.add(modelScene);

          }, undefined, function (error) {
            console.error(error);
          });

            loader.load('assets/model/Product_manegement.obj', function (object) {

            var modelScene = object;
            modelScene.position.set(0,-1,5);
            modelScene.scale.set(2,2,2);
            group.add(modelScene);

          }, undefined, function (error) {
            console.error(error);
          });

            loader.load('assets/model/Mould_die.obj', function (object) {

            var modelScene = object;
            modelScene.position.set(10,10,5);
            modelScene.scale.set(2,2,2);
            group.add(modelScene);

          }, undefined, function (error) {
            console.error(error);
          });

        loader.load('assets/model/Assembly.obj', function (object) {

            var modelScene = object;
            modelScene.position.set(0,0,80);
            modelScene.scale.set(2,2,2);
            group.add(modelScene);

          }, undefined, function (error) {
            console.error(error);
          });

          loader.load('assets/model/Computer_aided.obj', function (object) {

            var modelScene = object;
            modelScene.position.set(20,20,5);
            modelScene.scale.set(2,2,2);
            group.add(modelScene);

          }, undefined, function (error) {
            console.error(error);
          });

          loader.load('assets/model/Machiining.obj', function (object) {

            var modelScene = object;
            modelScene.position.set(30,30,5);
            modelScene.scale.set(2,2,2);
            group.add(modelScene);

          }, undefined, function (error) {
            console.error(error);
          });

          loader.load('assets/model/Product_concept.obj', function (object) {

            var modelScene = object;
            modelScene.position.set(40,40,5);
            modelScene.scale.set(2,2,2);
            group.add(modelScene);

          }, undefined, function (error) {
            console.error(error);
          });

          loader.load('assets/model/Product_delivery.obj', function (object) {

            var modelScene = object;
            modelScene.position.set(50,50,5);
            modelScene.scale.set(2,2,2);
            group.add(modelScene);

          }, undefined, function (error) {
            console.error(error);
          });

          this.scene.add(group);
```

Above code is loading all objects correctly on angular web application but positions are wrong.

**Expected result -> https://www.screencast.com/t/CJohlUOCGQ**

**Actual result -> https://www.screencast.com/t/JBDWsvMvd1fv**

Please help me how could I set x,y,z positions for all objects to get exact output.
Any type of help would be appreciated.

Comment: In the expected result I can see, that all objects should have the same "height axis" value, but in actual result, they are at different levels.
Which axis do you consider as a "height" axis? Maybe it doesn't match your scene axes?
Try to switch 'y' and 'z' values, like:
`.position.set.(x,z,y);`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably because the Y axis is confused with the Z axis.
There are two most popular approaches: Some people take Z as the **height axis** (and Y as a depth axis), and other people take Y as a **height axis** (and Z as a depth axis).

From the example photo (expected result) I can see, that all objects should have the same "height axis" value.

From your code I can see that you are considering Z as a **height axis**.
But looking at the colors of the arrows, we can see, that in your project Y is the **height axis.**
From three.js docs:

> The X axis is red. The Y axis is green. The Z axis is blue.

You should switch your Y and Z axes in your code. So, for example, instead of:

`modelScene.position.set(-17,-16,5);`

you should write:

`modelScene.position.set(-17,5,-16);`

Alternatively you can tell your camera, that your "height axis" is Z:

`camera.up = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1);`

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I've figure out issue anyhow.
Can you look at this screenshot and let me know what exactly have to do for this?
https://www.screencast.com/t/jJFd2GGxL

Comment: Just remove this line: `this.scene.add(new THREE.AxisHelper(200))`

Comment: Yeah got it! but after upgrading three.js to latest version mousedown and mouseup events stopped working, I want click events on each objects...how could I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "stopped working"?
Try to add a console.log("hello") at the begin of the event's function and check if it's working.

Comment: Yes already tried it..but nothing prints on console :(

Comment: Finally I've fixed it by changing version from latest (.121) to (.118) and events works fine with same code, looks like it's a bug of threejs latest version.